# Backup of Media

Tags: cache, media, backup

Recently had an issue with magento after doing a JS and CSS compression, which caused a few issues.  Nothing to major except for the fact that product images were missing from the catalog.  No big thing you would think, we have a back up.  This is where my problems start and hopefully a question someone can answer for me.

"The backup does not back up the full media" I have a few different backups and not one of them have the same media files backed up from the cache.  This has caused major headaches and left me with an unhappy customer.  Is this normal for Magento not to back up all media files?

Look forward to some responses on this.

Comment: What do you mean by doing JS/CSS compression?  Enabled standard merging in admin (which doesn't compress), used fooman speedster, something else?  Not clear why this would have caused images to then be 'missing'.

Answer (score 1):

By default Magento's backup system will only take a backup of the database.

It is highly recommended that you do not rely on the built-in backup system but instead go with a proper backup solution.

If you use a hosting control panel like cPanel, you will be able to take a backup directly within the control panel.

Answer (score 0):

As the answer above stated default behaviour is to only backup the database.

I would always use standalone backup process for database and media / non version controlled resources. This can range from simple Linux cron process to more advanced rsync etc to dedicated location.

If you are paying for support on your hosting speak to them as they can advise also.